# iOS Square Connect Merchant Authorization Issue

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, authorization, afnetworking-2, square-connect

**I'm having trouble authorizing a merchant in the Square OAuth** flow and am using AFNetworking 2.0 in Objective-C.  I called the method 'openURL' which brought up the Square log in page.  From here I can log in as a merchant, but then it never returns to the app.  Recommendations and code examples on what I need to do to get this to work would be much appreciated as I am very lost here.  Thanks in advance!

**OPEN URL Call**

The 'openURL' call successfully redirects the user to 'https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize' with the Client ID and Redirect URL on Safari.  After logging in and pressing "Allow" for the permissions, it doesn't jump back to the app.  The code I tried follows:

```
NSString *urlString= @"https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize";
NSString *clientID = @"client_id=[CLIENT_ID]";
NSString *responseType = @"response_type=code";
NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@&%@", urlString, clientID, responseType];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
```

I am thinking it may have something to do with the URLSchemes and URL identifier.  **Should the "Redirect URL" on the Square portal be the same as the URL Scheme or the URL identifier?**  I tried both and it didn't work.

**As an example, would the following values in my Info.plist be correct?** My URL Schemes single item is "iostestapp" and my URL identifier is "com.name.iostestapp".  The "Redirect URL" in the Square portal is "https://com.name.iostestapp".

**Is something else besides the code I provide needed?**  I've been seeing a lot about handlers concerning OAuth online but don't see that in the Square docs.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary for the user to authorize your developer application to access their data via the API. In order to do so, you must guide the user through the Square provided Oauth flow. It is not sufficient to programmatically perform a GET request to this URL. You must guide the user through the oauth flow in a web browser.

You can present the Oauth flow to your users by opening a web page with the following URL: https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID. The CLIENT_ID is the application identifier that you were provided when you registered your developer application in the Square developer portal. The developer portal is located at https://connect.squareup.com/apps. In the developer portal, you must also specify an oauth redirect_uri. After the user has authorized your application, they will be redirected to the redirect_uri that you specify with either an access token or a single use code (that can be exchanged by you for an access token.)

Also, please note that when you create an application in the developer portal, we provide you with a "personal access token" that you can use to perform API calls on behalf of your own user and test out the API.

Comment: Should I extract the single use code that is appended to the redirect URL with a webhook or something else?  The redirect URL I provided is a subdomain I created through my backend which is Parse.  I haven't done this before and haven't found much on it so I am not sure.  I read that a redirect in a browser counts as a GET request so I am looking for a way to grab the URL from that maybe if a webhook isn't right.  Parse has Cloud Code where I can do backend methods which I believe is needed here.